# Pytorch проблема регрессий нейросеть

Tags: python, pytorch

```
for i in range(0, 8):
    inputs= Inputs_arr
    outputs= Outputs_arr[:, i].reshape(-1, 1)
    
    sc = StandardScaler()
    inputs=sc.fit_transform(inputs)
    outputs=sc.fit_transform(outputs)
    inputs_normalized = preprocessing.normalize(inputs, norm='l2')
    normalizer = preprocessing.Normalizer().fit(inputs) 
    normalizer.transform(inputs)
    condition = np.isin(Inputs_arr[:,1], [8, 2])
    inputs_train, inputs_test = inputs[~condition], inputs[condition]
    outputs_train, outputs_test = outputs[~condition], outputs[condition]
    
    
    inputs_train_torch = torch.from_numpy(inputs_train).float()
    inputs_test_torch = torch.from_numpy(inputs_test).float()
    outputs_train_torch = torch.from_numpy(outputs_train).float()
    outputs_test_torch = torch.from_numpy(outputs_test).float()
    
    model = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(3, 24),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(24, 24),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(24, 1)
        )
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.09)
    for epoch in range(1000):
        output = model(inputs_train_torch)
        loss = criterion(output, torch.reshape(outputs_train_torch, (5760, 1)))
        print('Epoch: ', epoch, 'Loss: ', loss.item())
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Я не понял окончен ли модель или же нет, просто новичок и не знаю допустил ли я ошибки или же пропустил че то.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну, вы это запускали, сеть тренируется, ошибка уменьшается?

Comment: Да просто 1000 эпох это нормально? или много? и код который я написал это только трэнинг а тестовый какой будет? и R^2 коэффициент как можно узнать?